# Recibir como parámetro un número entre imprimir esa cantidad de caracteres

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Estoy intentando hacer un programa con una función que pide mediante inputbox un número impar del 5 al 10, y que repita el mensaje si no cumple las condiciones. Por otro lado, que un procedimiento reciba como parámetro dicho número para crear una `T` con `*`, con esas dimensiones en la ventana de inmediato *.*

Al ejecutarlo me da error de compilación en el `Public sub ejercicio1 ()`, donde pongo `dibujarT num`.

```vb
Public Sub ejercicio1()

    Dim num As Integer
    num = pedirnum()
    dibujarT num

End Sub

Public Function pedirnum() As Integer

    Dim num As Integer

    Do
        num = InputBox("Introducir un número entre el 5 y el 10: ")
    Loop While num < 5 Or num > 10 Or num Mod 2 = 0

End Function

Public Sub dibujarT(num As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer)

    For i = 1 To num
        For j = 1 To num
            If i = 1 Or j = (num \ 2) + 1 Then
                Debug.Print "*";
            Else
                Debug.Print
            End If
        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Cuando un código tiene un mensaje de error debe de incluir el mensaje de error textual. Referencia [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Al correr el código en VBA para Excel 2016 en inglés obtengo

> Compile error: Argument not optional.

[image]

Esto se traduce como error de compilación, argumento no opcional y quiere decir que la llamada que se está haciendo es incorrecta pues omite un argumento obligatorio.

La sentencia `Public Sub dibujarT(num As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer)` indica tres argumentos, los cuales son números enteros.

La "solución" sería llamar la función usando tres argumentos de tipo número, sin embargo esto no tiene sentido porque en la función dibujarT se declaran con valores de 1, por otro lado, hay otros errores.

Por ejemplo, en la función pedirnum falta la sentencia que asigna el valor a devolver.

Me parece que la documentación oficial sobre cómo [escribir una función](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/writing-a-function-procedure) sólo está disponible en inglés, así que te dejo una adapatación del ejemplo incluido en ella

```
Sub Main() 
 temp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _ 
 "Favor de escribir la temperatura en grados F.", Type:=1) 
 MsgBox "La temperatura es " &; Celsius(temp) &; " grados C." 
End Sub 

Function Celsius(fDegrees) 
 Celsius = (fDegrees - 32) * 5 / 9 
End Function
```

Espero que lo anterior te sirva para corregir tu código.